# SvelteKit hooks resolve callback not being called on every request

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I am working with SvelteKit v1.20.4 with Typescript.

I am trying to modify the HTML response for each incoming request in `hooks.server.ts`. I followed the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle) walkthrough.

Here's how the `src/hooks.server.ts` looks like -

```
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    
    const time = "time-" + new Date().getHours() // set up a custom class based on time of the day

    console.log("run hooks.server.ts"); // called on every request

    return await resolve(event, {
        transformPageChunk: ({ html }) => {
            console.log("Inside the transformPageChunk"); // not being called
            return html.replace(`%time%`, time);
           }
    });
};
```

Here's what `src/app.html` looks like -

```
<html lang="en" class="%time%">
...
```

On **every** request to the server - the outer `console.log` executes printing *run hooks.server.ts* but the `transformPageChunk` callback does not execute.

I want to make sure that the *resolve* callback is executed on every request. Only on manually refreshing the page the *resolve* callback runs.

How to solve this issue?